# Hive based data warehousing task- add sequence number to records

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a use case where in i need to implement SQL based data warehousing activities using Hive.

The software would generate a bunch of csv files. When it transforms into SQL table, an unique id called session is assigned for each csv file and loaded into a SQL table. Let's say, I have 3 columns in csv files. I will have four columns in the SQL table wherein the first column represent the session. This means that, values stored in first csv file is written into the SQL table with the sessios id '1', and values from the second csv file is appended to the SQL table with the session id '2', and so on.

In Hive,

I stored these csv files in hdfs directory and want to create one hive table with the additional columns that represents the session id. I am not sure how I can do it. Any help or clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to create the table without the additional column? How does the computer know what the id should be? Have you considered using he tagfile flag when reading files (so rather than adding an id on the fly, you add the name of the file as a column)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, that is, adding the name of the file instead of id. However, when I write my HQL query, I pick few values from multiple tables. In that case, I see an error popping up that INPUT__FILE__NAME is found in more than one tables. Any workaround here?

Comment: I fixed it. It was a simple mistake in my query. I  missed DISTINCT in the query. Thanks. I will still need to store the sesssions in a separate table for tracking which session is processed and which is not. I will do it with the help of  separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Try below approaches:

**Using Random session id:**

- create external table on top of source dataset:

`create external table staging (a string, b string, c string) location 'xyz';`

- Assign a unique id to each row:

`insert into table destination as  select reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") AS session_id, s.* from staging;`

**Using sequence number as session id:**

- create external table on top of source dataset:

`create external table staging (a string, b string, c string) location 'xyz';`

- first time data load:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS max_session_id (session_id int);`

- Append a sequence id to each record:

`insert into table destination
        select cast(coalesce(t.session_id,0) + row_number() over () as INT) as session_id, t1.* 
        from max_session_id t join destination t1 on 1=1;`

- Maintain max session id in separate table:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_max_session_id;
CREATE TABLE tmp_max_session_id AS SELECT COALESCE(MAX(session_id), 0) AS session_id FROM destination;`

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE max_session_id SELECT * FROM tmp_max_session_id;
```

if you want to tag a same session id per file then add each file as a partition, you may store reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") or max_session_id in separate table while adding partition use newly generated session_id as partition id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It is a good learning for me. Though, there is no need to assign a unique id for each record but need a sequence number for each and every file that are processed. Instead of INPUT__FILE__NAME, i like to see an integer. Nevertheless, I take your inputs for my future need.

Comment: you can use the second approach to generate sequence id for each file and add it as partition to your table.